# Affinity Designer: Hiding the Blue Outline on Selected Objects?

Tags: affinity-designer

In Affinity Designer, is there a way to hide the blue outline surrounding the vectors on selected objects - similarly to how Adobe Illustrator hides the blue lines going forward by pressing "CTRL + H"?

I often compare adjustments to a design by doing undos/redos and the blue vector outline changes what the design looks like.

Thanks for any help!

---

Affinity Designer selected object:

[image]

Illustrator Selected Object (what I'm looking for):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the view (hand) tool.

I don't know of any way to hide the selection, but I can prevent undo/redo from automatically selecting things by being careful about which tool I've got active.

If I've got the view tool active when I'm using CMD+Z and SHFT+CMD+Z, the object being modified by the action doesn't automatically select, but the object auto-selects if I've got most any other tool selected.

This accomplishes your goal of seeing un-outlined art as you cycle through undo/redo modes, it's just not exactly the same as how Adobe Illustrator does it.

And don't forget that Designer also has snapshots and cycle futures, which are powerful tools for comparing multiple states of your project without relying on undo/redo cycling.

Comment: "Not exactly the same as how Adobe Illustrator does it" - Perhaps that is the key. Thanks BESW!

Comment: @aero I hope it's helpful! I just added a mention of some Designer-specific tools that may also improve your workflow in this area.

Comment: Whoa snapshot looks really useful! The cycle futures looks promising as well. Thanks BESW!

Answer (score 2):

In the pulldown next to the snapping icon on the toolbar (the horseshoe magnet), there's an option called "Show snapping candidates". Uncheck that, and the purple outlines will go away.